# htaccess fallback rule for webm video files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webm

I would like to start using webm video files on my wordpress website.

Webm video files show correctly on Chrome and Firefox, but not on Internet Explorer.

So I'm trying to add an htaccess rule to replace webm with an mp4 file with same name when webm is unsupported by browser

- example -
  from https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/test.webm
  to https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/test.mp4

But it does not work.
Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !video/webm
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.mp4 -f
 RewriteRule (.+)\.webm$ $1.mp4 [T=video/mp4,E=REQUEST_video]
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts. Could you please do mention samples URLs FROM which TO which you want to redirect/rewrite in your question, that will help us to understand your question better, cheers.

Comment: I use a plugin for that. I think "WebP Express". But there are more assumingly.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "does not work"? Is the webm file still served and presumably fails in this browser? There's nothing particularly wrong with the rule you have posted. Although you are missing the `L` flag and where exactly are you using this rule in relation to your existing directives? Any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories? Do you have a front-end proxy that serves your static resources (this will effectively bypass `.htaccess` for these requests). Why are you setting the `REQUEST_video` env var - is this being used by something else?

Comment: Are you sure the browser you are testing is _not_ sending `video/webm` in the HTTP `Accept` header?

Comment: Hi MrWhite, on IE i just see this error on the embed video:  "Error: Unsupported video type or invalid file path"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested I've managed to find a working alternative solution with jQuery:

```
function webm_fallback()
{
    if (is_single()) {

        ?>
<script>
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
// detect Internet Explorer
        if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ) || (!!document.documentMode == true )){
// replace 
            $('source').each(function(){
                var source = $(this).attr('src');
                $(this).attr('src',source.replace('.webm', '.mp4'));
                $(this).prop('type','video/mp4');            

            });       
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
    </script>
<?php
    }
}

add_action('wp_head', 'webm_fallback');
```

Comment: This is "browser detection". If you are going to implement it in this way then you could just detect the browser in `.htaccess` and issue a redirect. An issue here is that MSIE _can_ support `video/mp4` if the appropriate codecs are installed in the OS (which is what the `.htaccess` solution in your question is detecting - "feature detection").